# How/where can I inspect JS methods' internal code?

Tags: javascript

For example, when we pass a callback function to `Array.filter()`:

```
[1,2,3].filter(el => {
  return el === 2;
})
```

I'd like to inspect the internals of the method, leading up to the callback at the end

Comment: Then you will have to check the source code of the JavaScript engine of your browser. But the question is "why" would you want to know how the function is implemented

Comment: The JavaScript engines are mostly open source. [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8) is the most popular, arguably. [SpiderMonkey, for Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/SpiderMonkey/Getting_SpiderMonkey_source_code) and [JavaScriptCore, for WebKit (Safari)](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/tree/master/Source/JavaScriptCore) are also available.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, perhaps the closest you'd get is to look at the source code for your favourite Javascript interpreter, or you could look at the polyfill code which is presented for certain methods - `filter` being one - on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

eg

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter){
  Array.prototype.filter = function(func, thisArg) {
    'use strict';
    if ( ! ((typeof func === 'Function' || typeof func === 'function') && this) )
        throw new TypeError();

    var len = this.length >>> 0,
        res = new Array(len), // preallocate array
        t = this, c = 0, i = -1;

    var kValue;
    if (thisArg === undefined){
      while (++i !== len){
        // checks to see if the key was set
        if (i in this){
          kValue = t[i]; // in case t is changed in callback
          if (func(t[i], i, t)){
            res[c++] = kValue;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      while (++i !== len){
        // checks to see if the key was set
        if (i in this){
          kValue = t[i];
          if (func.call(thisArg, t[i], i, t)){
            res[c++] = kValue;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    res.length = c; // shrink down array to proper size
    return res;
  };
}
```

Comment: I think this is what he is searching for. I just add a link to the general documentation page : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference